# Hover on Navbar Social Icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I can get the hover effect of the icon over just the font awesome, but not over the complete separate elements. And I want each element to have its original color on hover.

how can I get the right hover effect?

Here is the HTML Code used

```html
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right socialnav">
                <li class="twitternav"><a href="https://twitter.com/HHAesthetics"TARGET="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li class="facebooknav"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hardyhealthaesthetics/?fref=ts"TARGET="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li class="instagramnav"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/hardyhealthaesthetics/"TARGET="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li class="youtubenav"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLl1_1qs9nAtPLcMfQNJNhQ"TARGET="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:hardyhealthaesthetics@gmail.com"_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-to">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-us" class="scroll-to">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#our-service" class="scroll-to">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#body" class="scroll-to">BODY SCULPTING</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#cli" class="scroll-to">Clinical</a></li>
                 <!--<li><a href="#test" class="scroll-to">Testimonials</a></li>-->
                
                <li><a href="#gale" class="scroll-to">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#promo" class="scroll-to">PROMOTIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team" class="scroll-to">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-to">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And here is the CSS code that I have tried.

```html
.navbar-right .socialnav > li .facebooknav a:hover {
    color: #4060A5 !important;
    }
.social .fa-twitter:hover {
    color: #00ABE3;
}
.social .fa-instagram:hover {
color:#517fa4;
}
.social .fa-youtube:hover {
color:#C31A1E;
}
```

The website is http://www.hardyhealth.com/ (top bar social media icons)

Any help would be awesome thank you!!!

Comment: Try `.twitternav:hover .fa { color: #yourcolor; }`. And so on.

Comment: RAC YOU SIR ARE A GENIUS! It worked! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Sure, I'll turn this to an answer. That way you can mark it correct, just in case people have a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.twitternav:hover .fa { color: #yourcolor; }`. And so on.